# Do non-fatals participate in overall statistics (eg. crash-free users, crash-free sessions etc.)?

Tags: crash-reports, crashlytics, google-fabric

Do non-fatals participate in overall statistics (eg. crash-free users, crash-free sessions etc.)? Or maybe theirs function is strictly informal?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've got this answer from Crashlytics team:

> Non-fatals do not affect the crash-free users or sessions data in any way.